# Why some fonts (e.g. Code 128) work locally but not in server when generating pdf file with PDFsharp

Tags: asp.net, truetype, pdfsharp

I'm creating some labels with PDFsharp (using ASP.Net+VB) and everything works OK in my development PC: the PDF file shows correctly the sizes and fonts I choose (Code 128, for barcodes, and Arial. Booth are ttf).

When publishing the code to the server the generated PDF shows `Microsoft Sans MS` instead of `Code 128`. The pdf is being generated in the server and downloaded to the client (My PC), and I can't see the bar codes in generated PDF neither in server nor in client.

I'm sure the font is installed in the Server and my local PC (I can open a MS Word Document and use the font).

```
Private loFuenteCode128 As XFont = New XFont("Code 128", 26, XFontStyle.Regular)
```

It looks to me that the problem is somewhere in the server (Windows 2008).

Comment: Do you see Arial in the PDF or only Microsoft Sans MS? Maybe insufficient rights. Try running with an application pool that uses the Local System account.

Comment: Yes, I tried using four different fonts in the same page: Arial, Tahoma, Calibri and Code 128. All but Code 128 where correctly displayed. Please, read my answer bellow: my problem was trivial, but it looks like there still are issues with some "kind" of TT fonts. And thanks for helping so quick, PDFsharp is great! :)=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Found the problem (kind of): I just gave total rights to the font `Code 128` to the *users* group (yes I know, I'm in a hurry...) and restarted the server (I hadn't restarted since I installed the font). I'm not sure what fixed the problem but I have to move to another issue now.

**Some thing else**: The original problem holds for "some"  windows fonts (tested in local PC and two different servers), for example: I can use `Courier New`, but not `Courier`. I tried some fonts and it looks like I can use "fonts with styles" (I mean: those which include regular and at least another style in the ttf file); but when I try fonts that only have "regular" style it prints `Microsoft Sans MS` instead. I leave it here in case somebody else can benefits from my findings :)

[image: Fonts which work and doesn't work]