# PDFSharp Monospace fonts

Tags: pdfsharp, monospace

I have been having issues trying to get third party monospaced fonts to work properly with PDFsharp. I'm simply installing these fonts to the windows OS.

I do not want to use standard monospace fonts such as Courier new or Consolas.

I have tried many monospace fonts, they all seem to suffer from the same problem when being used by PDFsharp - Their letter spacing is rendered incorrectly (but consistently).

I can get third party non-monospaced fonts to work just fine, such as open sans.

Here are a couple of examples of fonts and their rendered outputs:

[image: PDFSHarp Fonts]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if PDFsharp uses a different font for measuring, not the font used for drawing.

Did you reboot the computer after installing the fonts? If the problem persists after a reboot, an SSCCE will help to replicate the problem.
http://sscce.org/

Comment: Yes, i have rebooted several times. No problem doing an sscce. Where shall I put it?

Comment: @dalemac If the ZIP is small enough and not confidential, you can put it on the forum: http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewforum.php?f=2 Or put it anywhere and give us a link. Are you using PDFsharp 1.32 or 1.50 beta?

Comment: OK, i'll build an sscce now. I'm using 1.32, but I can't se any reason not to upgrade to the 1.50 beta.

Comment: I built an sscce, ran it, and it displayed the font perfectly. I ran my main PDF builder and now that too is rendering these fonts perfectly! I hate it when these type of things happen!

Comment: Pushed the code to a dev server and have the same issue, but this time running the sscce works but main app still doesn't.

Comment: @dalemac: After a server re-boot? Could be a problem with access rights (user used by IIS cannot access fonts). See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27894977/162529

Comment: Nope, it was using the font but the character width was wrong. I ended up forcibly deleting the fonts cache file and then doing a reboot, after that all was well.